# Apache HttpClient not executing third request

Tags: java, apache

I'm using Apache HttpClient to do a multipart request to upload a file, but it doesn't work after the third request.

Here is my code :

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

Map<String, String> requestParams = new HashMap<>();
requestParams.put("param1", "myrequestparam");

String url = UPLOAD_URL + "?param1=" + myRequestParam;

HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                    .addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, "file")
                    .build();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(entity);

try {

    httpClient.execute(request);

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
}
```

It is executing multiple times, works fines the two firsts times, but nothing happen the third time.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call

```
EntityUtils.consume(entity)
```

at the end of your code to close your request. Than start the next post.
[doc](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html)

Or you can read the tutorial [pdf](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiniOqDzZHXAhXDAxoKHW5lDK8QFggtMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhc.apache.org%2Fhttpcomponents-client-ga%2Ftutorial%2Fpdf%2Fhttpclient-tutorial.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2tb6jdncQo_ICTF3qdPWuq)